# Ruby on rails : optimize code structure and minimize strings declaration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, optimization, refactoring

I have a module **DownloadReportHelper** and 4 methods that contain and return many strings declaration which are almost similar.

```
module DownloadReportHelper

  def self.pdf_file_name(report)
    report_date         = report.created_at.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
    contract_name       = report.activities[0].contract.name.gsub("/", "_")
    [ contract_name, report_date, report.reference.to_s ].join('_')
  end

  def self.generate_public_and_internal_pdf(report, current_company)
    FileUtils.mkdir_p( "tmp/pdf/#{current_company.subdomain}/reports/#{report.reference}" )
    [ generate_public_pdf(report, current_company), generate_internal_pdf(report, current_company) ]
  end

  def self.generate_public_pdf(report, current_company)
    attachement_name = pdf_file_name(report)
    public_pdf = ReportPdf.new(current_company, report, [])
    public_pdf.generate_file( "#{current_company.subdomain}/reports/#{ report.reference }/#{ attachement_name }.pdf" )
    "#{ Rails.root }/tmp/pdf/#{current_company.subdomain}/reports/#{ report.reference }/#{ attachement_name }"
  end

  def self.generate_internal_pdf(report, current_company)
    attachement_name = pdf_file_name(report) + "_internal"
    internal_pdf = ReportPdf.new(current_company, report, [], "internal")
    internal_pdf.generate_file( "#{current_company.subdomain}/reports/#{ report.reference }/#{ attachement_name }.pdf" )
    "#{ Rails.root }/tmp/pdf/#{current_company.subdomain}/reports/#{ report.reference }/#{ attachement_name }"
  end
end
```

I want to customize code and minimize the strings paths declaration like : 
    ***"tmp/pdf/#{current_company.subdomain}/reports/#{report.reference}"***

in my module by using a global variables, can some one give some help please !

Answer (score 1):

I was able to DRY it, but I am not sure the code became more readable.

```
module DownloadReportHelper
  class << self
    def pdf_file_name(report)
      report_date = report.created_at.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
      contract_name = report.activities[0].contract.name.gsub("/", "_")
      [contract_name, report_date, report.reference].join('_')
    end

    def path(company, report, prefix = [], suffix = [])
      [
        *prefix,
        current_company.subdomain, reports, report.reference,
        *suffix
      ]
    end

    def generate_pdf(report, current_company, type)
      args = [current_company, report, []]
      args << type unless type == "public"
      pdf = ReportPdf.new(*args)

      path = path(*args, [], "#{pdf_file_name(report)}.pdf")
      pdf.generate_file(path.join("/"))
      [Rails.root, "tmp", "pdf", *path].join("/")
    end

    TYPES = %w[internal public]

    TYPES.each do |type|
      define_method("generate_#{type}_pdf") do |report, current_company| 
        generate_pdf(report, current_company, type)
      end
    end

    def generate_public_and_internal_pdf(report, current_company)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p(path(current_company, report, %w[tmp pdf])
      TYPES.map { |type| generate_pdf(report, current_company, type)}
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this solution, as Aleksei answer, I think you will loose some readibility.

```
module DownloadReportHelper
  class << self
    def pdf_file_name(report)
      report_date         = report.created_at.strftime("%y-%m-%d")
      contract_name       = report.activities[0].contract.name.gsub("/", "_")
      [ contract_name, report_date, report.reference.to_s ].join('_')
    end

    def generate_public_and_internal_pdf(report, current_company)
      FileUtils.mkdir_p( "tmp/pdf/#{dirname(report, current_company)}" )
      [ generate_public_pdf(report, current_company), generate_internal_pdf(report, current_company) ]
    end

    def generate_public_pdf(report, current_company)
      @pdf_type = :public
      @pdf_instance = ReportPdf.new(current_company, report, [])
      generate_file(report, current_company)
    end

    def generate_internal_pdf(report, current_company)
      @pdf_type = :internal
      @pdf_instance = ReportPdf.new(current_company, report, [], "internal")
      generate_file(report, current_company)
    end

    private 

    def generate_file(report, current_company)
      @pdf_instance.generate_file(filepath(report, current_company))
      "#{Rails.root}/tmp/pdf/#{filepath(report, current_company)}"
    end

    def dirname(report, current_company)
      "#{current_company.subdomain}/reports/#{report.reference}"
    end

    def filepath(report, current_company)
      attachement_name = pdf_file_name(report)
      if @pdf_type == :internal
        attachement_name = attachement_name + '_internal'
      end
      "#{dirname(report, current_company)}/#{attachement_name}.pdf"
    end
  end
end
```

If you don't really need `generate_public_pdf` and `generate_internal_pdf` to be called from a class, and are just helper functions to `generate_public_and_internal_pdf` then you could make `report` and `current_company` class variables as well and increase the readibility.

The solution depends on how you intend to use the code.